# Regex: How do I exclude commas when in my pattern?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I want to find the first number that is sandwiched with commas on either end, and I came up with this:

```
m = re.search("\,([0-9])*\,",line)
```

However, this returns to me the number with the commas, how do I exclude them?

`m.group(0)` returns

```
',1620693,'
```

Comment: I guess your expression should be actually `",([0-9]*),"` (star inside the group).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`group(0)` will always return the entire match.

See python documentation:

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+)", "Isaac Newton, physicist")
>>> m.group(0)       # The entire match
'Isaac Newton'
>>> m.group(1)       # The first parenthesized subgroup.
'Isaac'
```

Comment: m.group(1) returns only the last digit of the number?

Comment: Here:
`>>> population.group(1)`
`'1'`
`>>> population.group(0)`
`',2503281,'`

Answer (score 3):

Use `m.group(1)`.  You also don't need to escape (backslash) the commas.  `m.group(0)` refers to the entire match, and each number after that refers to matched groups.